# Blender 2.8 Cell Fracture Rigid Body Won't stand up

Tags: rigidbody

I am trying to animate a cell fractured rigid body wall being hit by an object and crumbling.  I have created the Cell Fracture wall with a rigid body that is animated.  When I initially press play the entire all fall infinitely as I would expect.    I want the Wall to stay stationary until struct by another object.  In the physics tab, I have checked the deactivation mark and the start deactivation checkbox.  But when I press play the wall still falls.

I can get the expected result if I Start with an empty blend file but when I add this structure to an existing blend file it will not work.  It's making me crazy.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.